# Use assigned value in Vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I need some help with my VBA Script.

I need to use already assign value in vlookup formula in vba script.

Currently i'm using the below code as you can see i have already assigned Value Like "Path", "Work_sheet", "Sheet_no".

Now i want to use my assign value VBA

Required VBA

```
Range("C9").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A8,'& Path & Work_sheet & sheets_no &'!$A$14:$B$14,2,FALSE)"
```

Currently using VBA

```
Path ="C:\Users\Desktop\iMAGE lINK cHECKING\"
Work_sheet = "[Main Image Link.xlsm]"

sheets_no = "Sheet1"
Range("C9").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A8,'C:\Users\Desktop\iMAGE lINK cHECKING\[Main Image Link.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$14:$B$14,2,FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes were mismatched and the & need to be outside of quotes so the substitution can be made.

```
Range("C9").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A8,'" & Path & Work_sheet & sheets_no & "'!$A$14:$B$14,2,FALSE)"
```

HTH

Comment: Please do not post just code as answer, but explain why this would work to solve the problem. Without context your answer is likely to be deleted because of Low-Quality flagging.